# Fluent NHibernate is bringing ClassMap Id and SubClassMap Id to referenced table?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

HI,

I have the following entities I'm trying to map:

```
public class Product {
   public int ProductId { get; private set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialProduct : Product {
   public ICollection<Option> Options { get; private set; }
}

public class Option {
   public int OptionId { get; private set; }
}
```

And the following mappings:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product> {
  public ProductMap() {
    Id( x => x.ProductId );
    Map( x => x.Name );
}

public class SpecialProductMap : SubclassMap<SpecialProduct> {
  public SpecialProductMap() {
    Extends<ProductMap>();
    HasMany( p => p.Options ).AsSet().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
  }
}

public class OptionMap : ClassMap<Option> {
  public OptionMap() {
    Id( x => x.OptionId );
  }
}
```

The problem is that my tables end up like this:

```
Product
--------
ProductId
Name

SpecialProduct
--------------
ProductId

Option
------------
OptionId
ProductId          // This is wrong
SpecialProductId   // This is wrong
```

There should only be the one ProductId and single reference to the SpecialProduct table, but we get "both" Ids and two references to SpecialProduct.ProductId.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Can you show how you *want* your tables to end up?

Comment: There are two `ProductId` columns because the `SpecialProduct` table has to join back to `Product` somehow, it's a foreign-key.

As for the `Option` table, that genuinely looks wrong. You may have encountered a bug. I've opened a [ticket](http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236-fnh/tickets/184-hasmany-in-subclass-generates-wrong-foreign-keys) for it, and I'll investigate it later.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue with the information provided. Please could you comment on the ticket I linked to previously with as much extra information as you can provide. A stripped down solution reproducing the issue would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback everyone.

The tables I wanted look like this:

```
Product 
-------- 
ProductId 
Name 

SpecialProduct 
-------------- 
ProductId 

Option 
------------ 
OptionId 
SpecialProductId   // Which ends up being just product id, but the FK here is to SpecialtyProduct
```

I had forgotten to add this line in in my original question to the OptionMap class:

```
public class OptionMap : ClassMap<Option> {      
  public OptionMap() {      
    Id( x => x.OptionId );      
    References( x => x.ParentOption );
  }      
}
```

If I then use this instead, it works as I want:

```
public class OptionMap : ClassMap<Option> {      
  public OptionMap() {      
    Id( x => x.OptionId );      
    References( x => x.ParentOption ).Column( "SpecialProductId" ).Not.Nullable();
  }      
}
```

It looks Fluent was adding "ProductId" due to the references and didn't figure out that the appropariate column was already there.